# Hash.fetch(not_exist_key) raises IndexError instead of KeyError

Tags: ruby, exception, doc

In the docs, it says:

> fetch(key [, default] ) → obj ; fetch(key) {| key | block } → obj
>
> Returns a value from the hash for the given key. If the key can’t be found, there are several options: With no other arguments, it will raise an **KeyError** exception; if default is given, then that will be returned; if the optional code block is specified, then that will be run and its result returned.

In my terminal, irb says:

```
irb(main):001:0> hash = { 1 => "No one", 2 => "gonna", 3 => "fetch me" }
=> {1=>"No one", 2=>"gonna", 3=>"fetch me"}

irb(main):002:0> hash.fetch(4)
IndexError: key not found
    from (irb):2:in `fetch'
    from (irb):2
    from :0
```

Can you help me explain that?

Comment: what version of ruby you are using? for me it is OK..

Comment: ruby 1.9.1 and irb 0.9.5. Yes i know but it's just a little curiosity. The docs is different from reality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are using an older version of Ruby. According to the [1.8.7 docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) it raises an `IndexError`:

> Returns a value from the hash for the given key. If the key can’t be
>   found, there are several options: With no other arguments, it will
>   raise an **IndexError** exception; if default is given, then that will be
>   returned; if the optional code block is specified, then that will be
>   run and its result returned.

Note that [`KeyError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/KeyError.html) is a subclass of [`IndexError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IndexError.html) in Ruby 1.9+, so rescuing `IndexError` works, too.

Comment: oh, i realise that there exists 2 version of ruby in my computer. Maybe i'm using the 1.8version. How do I switch to ruby1.9?

Comment: I'm using [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) to switch Ruby versions, but [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and [RVM](https://rvm.io) are popular, too.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ruby 1.9.3p0 and have no problems:

```
irb(main):001:0> hash = { 1 => "No one", 2 => "gonna", 3 => "fetch me" }
    => {1=>"No one", 2=>"gonna", 3=>"fetch me"}

irb(main):002:0> hash.fetch(4) 

KeyError: key not found: 4
    from (irb):2:in `fetch'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/marek/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

irb(main):003:0> hash.fetch(1) 
=> "No one"
```

Comment: what's your version of irb?

Comment: thanks. i figure out that my irb point to ruby1.8 directory. i'll change that